# Python cgi script doesnot work properly

Tags: python, html

When i generate html in my python cgi script it doesnt show!But when i open this empty page by source code in IE and copy in txt(html) file and then open it by IE it works fine!Cannot understand why it happened if generated code is ok!
Anyone please,tell me can I fix it or it not?
My python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-

import cgi

def select_graph_view():
    print "Content-Type: text/html\n"

    print '<html>'
    print'<head>'
    print('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">')
    print('<title>Highcharts Example</title>')
    print '<script type="text/javascript" src="d:\slider\web_server3\cgi-bin\js_css\jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>'
    print'<script type="text/javascript">'
    print'$(function () {'
    print'$' + '('+"'#container').highcharts({"
    print'        title: {'
    print"            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',"
    print'            x: -20 //center'
    print'        },'
    print'        subtitle: {'
    print"            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',"
    print'            x: -20'
    print'        },'
    print'        xAxis: {'
    print"            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',"
    print"                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']"
    print'        },'
    print'        yAxis: {'
    print'            title: {'
    print"                text: 'Temperature (°C)'"
    print'            },'
    print'            plotLines: [{'
    print'                value: 0,'
    print'                width: 1,'
    print'                color: '+"'#808080'"
    print'            }]'
    print'        },'
    print'        tooltip: {'
    print"            valueSuffix: '°C'"
    print'        },'
    print'        legend: {'
    print"            layout: 'vertical',"
    print"            align: 'right',"
    print"            verticalAlign: 'middle',"
    print'            borderWidth: 0'
    print'        },'
    print'        series: [{'
    print"            name: 'Tokyo',"
    print'            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]'
    print'        }, {'
    print"            name: 'New York',"
    print'            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]'
    print'        }, {'
    print"            name: 'Berlin',"
    print'            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]'
    print'        }, {'
    print"            name: 'London',"
    print'            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]'
    print'        }]'
    print'    });'
    print'});'
    print'  </script>'
    print'</head>'
    print'<body>'
    print'<script src="d:\slider\web_server3\cgi-bin\js_css\hightharts_js\highcharts.js"></script>'
    print'<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>'
    print'</body>'
    print'</html>'
    select_graph_view() <------------ call my def
```

and HTML code from empty generated page:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Highcharts Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d:\slider\web_server3\cgi-bin\js_css\jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () {
       $('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (?C)'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '?C'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
    }, {
        name: 'Berlin',
        data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
    }]
  });
});
</script>
  </head>
    <body>
     <script src="d:\slider\web_server3\cgi-bin\js_css\hightharts_js\highcharts.js"></script>
     <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you're doing this as CGI at all. You're not doing any server-side processing, so a static HTML file would be more appropriate. (And if you *are* going to do server-side processing, you should be using a proper templating system.)

However I would be amazed if serving your JS files on a file path - `d:\whatever` - rather than a web URL was actually working.

Comment: this path d:\whatever was only for explorering this problem, if it woud work with this path my python simpe server's cgi script works from cgi-bin library of course.I have python's base HttpServer and static html in which I call my cgi scripts, but not using do_GET methods

Answer (score 0):

you need to run a cgi webserver to execute the python script. Create a cgi_testserver.py in your root application folder with this:

```
import CGIHTTPServer
import BaseHTTPServer

class Handler(CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler):
        cgi_directories = ["/cgi-bin"]

PORT = 5001
httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Then create a /cgi-bin/ directory, place your python script in there and call it in the HTML file like so:

```
http://localhost:5001/cgi-bin/name_of_python_script.py
```

instead of:

```
d:\slider\web_server3\cgi-bin\js_css\hightharts_js\highcharts.js
```

Comment: My CGIHttpServer exectly like yours, when i excecute my cgi with matplotlib, it works, but in my example i am trying to use highcharts.js library it doesn't(.Maybe it woudn't work with higthcharts, interesting why.Thanks for your answer! P.S as you can see i want plot my data with higtharts only

Comment: Which browser are you using to access the page? Chrome has some funky issues if loaded from file:// (localhost). Does it load in Firefox or Safari?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your dev console when opening the web page in the browser?

Comment: yes, when output $function(){ (line 7 symbol 1) appears "assumes the existence of object"((